# Jenkins error - Unable to access application source information in '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-/W3C/DTD HTML 4.0 Draft/EN">/app/myApp.war

Tags: jenkins, weblogic11g

I am trying to build and deploy through `Jenkins` in `weblogic 11g` server, but I am getting following error,

```
[java] Unexpected Error Initializing Deployer: weblogic.management.ManagementException
[Deployer:149003]Unable to access application source information in '<!DOCTYPE HTML
PUBLIC"-/W3C/DTD HTML 4.0 Draft/EN">/app/myApp.war' for application   `myApp.war'. 
The specific error is: No application files exist.
```

I am using `weblogic.Deployer` to deploy. Any idea how I can get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using -remote and -upload command line parameters. It worked for me when using the call to weblogic.Deployer through wls deployer plugin.